# How to modify a TikZ premade picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've modified a simple cycle diagram from TikZ code written by Author: Jérôme Tremblay, Published 2012-02-18, as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {3}
\def \radius {1.5cm}
\def \margin {25} % margin in angles, depends on the radius
\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
 \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (1- \s)}:\radius) {$\s$};
 \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and which results in the following TikZ picture. Note I made two pictures with the arrows going in different directions:

[image]

I want to make two changes:

1. change the numbers to math symbols $\bar{e}_1$, $\bar{e}_2$ and $\bar{e}_3$. The symbols do not need to be enclosed in a circle.
2. add the following to the center of the cycle diagram: (+).

Kindly let me know also, if there is an easier way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragments into a compilable document that people can play with. Also, if the source is an answer on the site, please link directly to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are very simple additions to the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {3}
\def \radius {1.5cm}
\def \margin {25} % margin in angles, depends on the radius
\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (1- \s)}:\radius) {$\bar{e}_\s$};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
  \node at (0,0) {$-$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {3}
\def \radius {1.5cm}
\def \margin {25} % margin in angles, depends on the radius
\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle]  at ({360/\n * (1- \s)}:\radius) {$\bar{e}_\s$};
  \draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\node at (0,0) {$+$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Such easy-looking modifications. I am grateful for the quick reply and solution.

Comment: Since this solved your problem, it's helpful to "Accept" the answer by clicking the green checkmark icon beside it.  And for future questions, please don't post just fragments of code.

Comment: Thank you for that information. If I understand correctly, the checkmark is originally gray and turns green once I click on it? I appreciate the assistance and the directions on etiquette using this forum. You've been quite helpful.